# 'count' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'

Tags: ios, swift

I am having an issue with passing a value to  a class in swift.I have the ViewControler.swift that creates the object and other UI sort of stuff. Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    //creates the Intractive button objects

    @IBOutlet var Bag1: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var Bag2: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var Bag3: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var lblTokenSlider: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var slider: UIStepper!

    @IBOutlet var Go: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var counter: UILabel!


    var count  = 10
    var noOfBags = 3
    //gives acces to game AP!
    var gameAPI = GameAPI(noOfBags: count, noOfTokens: noOfBags )

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        lblTokenSlider.hidden = true
        slider.hidden = true
        Go.hidden = true
        counter.hidden = true
        Bag3.hidden = false
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Event Drivers

    @IBAction func btnBag1(sender: AnyObject) {
        Bag1.userInteractionEnabled = false
        Bag2.userInteractionEnabled = false
        Bag3.userInteractionEnabled = false

    }


    @IBAction func btnBag2(sender: AnyObject) {

    }

    @IBAction func btnBag3(sender: AnyObject) {

    }

    @IBAction func SliderAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    }
    @IBAction func RemoveTokens(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    }
}
```

And here is my gameAPI:

```
import Foundation

private enum MoveError: ErrorType {
    case Empty
}
class GameAPI {
    var noOfBags: Int
    var bagArray:[Bag] = []

    init(noOfBags: Int, noOfTokens : Int){
        self.noOfBags = noOfBags
        for _ in 0..<noOfBags {
            bagArray.append(Bag(counter: noOfTokens))
        }
    }

    /* Returns the amount of counters are in a bag */
    func getCounts(i :Int ) -> Int {
        return bagArray[i].getCount()
    }

    func isBagEmpty(i: Int) -> Bool {
        if (bagArray[i].getCount() <= 0){
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }

    func removeCounter(bagToRemove: Int, counters: Int ) throws{
        do {
            try self.bagArray[bagToRemove].removeCount(counters)
        }
        catch{
            throw MoveError.Empty
        }
    }

}
```

The Issue is where I declare GameAPI in the ViewController and I  get 
' Instance member 'count' cannot be used on type 'ViewController''
 on line
`var gameAPI = GameAPI(noOfBags: count, noOfTokens: noOfBags )`

But if I was to switch the variables out and used fixed values like:
`var gameAPI = GameAPI(noOfBags: 10, noOfTokens: 3 )`

It works fine. I really dont understand why this is not working.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have the initializer of an instance variable using another instance variable. In general, you cannot use an instance variable until all the instance variables are initialized. Therefore you have to break the dependency between instance variables.

You have several options:

1. Move your initialization to an ininitalizer. That's a bit difficult with `UIViewController` though because you need at least two initializers, leading to code duplication:

   ```
   init(...) {
      let count = 10
      let noOfBags = 3 

      self.count = count
      self.noOfBags = noOfBags
      self.gameAPI = GameAPI(noOfBags: count, noOfTokens: noOfBags)

      super.init(...)
   }
   ```
2. Declare `count` and `noOfBags` as global constants:

   ```
   static let count = 10
   static let noOfBags = 3
   ```

   Therefore your `GameAPI` initializer won't use `self`.
3. If you need `count` and `noOfBags` as variables, you can create global constants `initialCount` and `initialNoOfBags` and then

   ```
   var count = initialCount
   var noOfBags = initialNoOfBags
   var gameAPI = GameAPI(noOfBags: initialCount, noOfTokens: initialNoOfBags)
   ```
4. You can initialize your `gameAPI` lazily:

   ```
   lazy var gameAPI: GameAPI = GameAPI(noOfBags: self.count, noOfTokens: self.noOfBags)
   ```

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for the comment, I don't know the syntax for lazy variables well because I don't use them frequently.

Comment: No problem :) I have deleted my comment now that you've made the change.

Comment: Thank you! I used static and I tried your 4th suggestion but came with the error ``Value of type 'NSObject -> () -> ViewController' has no member 'count'``

Comment: @Osian Didn't you forget the `: GameAPI` part? The type definition is required there.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you can only declare variable outside any method in your `ViewController` class. but you can not assign any variable outside any method.

Suppose you are declaring one variable like:

```
let tempVar = 0
```

Which is outside of method but inside your view controller class like:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let tempVar = 0
}
```

Now if you create another variable inside your class like:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let tempVar = 0

    let tempVar2 = tempVar
}
```

And you are giving a value to that variable `tempVar2` is `tempVar`. Which will give you an error like:

```
Instance member 'tempVar' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'
```

You are getting this because you are assigning value to `tempVar2` instance at wrong place. you can solve this error by assigning values into `viewDidLoad` method or in any other method this way:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let tempVar = 0

    var tempVar2 = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        tempVar2 = tempVar
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of a default value you can make the variable an implicitly unwrapped optional. That's common with 2-phase initialization.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks for your comment. But I try to explain him with very simple example.. :)

Answer (score -1):

In Swift you cannot use instance properties within a property initializer because property initializers run before 'self' is available.

You can fix this by making your `gameAPI` variable a computed property instead.

So instead of:

```
var count  = 10
var noOfBags = 3
var gameAPI = GameAPI(noOfBags: count, noOfTokens: noOfBags)
```

Try this:

```
var count  = 10
var noOfBags = 3
var gameAPI: GameAPI {
    return GameAPI(noOfBags: count, noOfTokens: noOfBags)
}
```

Comment: Probably you don't want a computed variable but a lazy initialization instead. Big difference.

Comment: What's the issue with a computed variable in this case?

Comment: It will create a new instance every time you call it. Therefore you cannot mutate it because the second time you call it you will get a new instance again.